# TS function having types as ( A | B ), has single return type B. How do i accomplish this without getting type error?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For example here is the simple function :

```
interface InputTime {
      month : number,
      year : number
}

const getMonthAndYear = (time: InputTime | Date): InputTime => {

    if(isValid(time)) {
        // time is a date object
        return {month: time.getMonth(), year: time.getFullYear()}
    } else {
        // time is a month object
        return {...time}
    }
}
```

So here TypeScript gives 2 errors:

1. on first return statement it says : Property 'getMonth' does not exist on type 'InputTime | Date'.
2. on Second return statement if fails due to thinking its type Date

So how can i type define this function to work as expected ?

Edit :

Answering the comment about isValid function types :
[image]

Edit 2 :

from further reading answers i created this function :

```
const _type_safe_isValidDate = (time:any):time is Date => {
    return isValid(time)
}
```

And error went away. But is this the only solution ? Is there better way so i can write some type guard around those third party library functions that i am using in my code and not create wrapper function just for type safety ?

Comment: `isValid` should probably be [a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) so the compiler knows what `time` is.

Comment: What is the logic for `isValid` function?

Comment: Use moment js for checking, analyzing and returning values: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: In my opinion this is over complicating something that you can code and solve in a few minutes. Sometimes the easy way IS the right way. Either create 2 methods, each accepting a different type or use `any`.

Comment: @garethb i understand that for this simple example it may be too much. But for other complex functions i want to know if there is option to do something with generic types or some things else that i don't know of yet.

Comment: @Luciano I don't think Moment.JS is relevant here. The code involves dates but the question is about the general behaviour of handling union types. Moment does nothing with this, even in the current case.

Comment: @garethb I'd say you're overcomplicating the solution. It's literally just a basic type guard needed. Even a `time instanceof Date` is going to be a sufficient solution, as it's a valid type guard, thus not even needing an extra type guard function. In any case, union handling is a very basic problem in TypeScript. Making the type `any` just means you close your eyes to both the problem and the actual solution. The easiest path in that case is to just not use TS at all, since if you ignore types, then you basically invalidate TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fix this by updating your custom type guard `isValid` like:

```
function isValid(date: any): date is Date {
    return 'getMonth' in date;
}
```

and then you can call `getMonthAndYear()` like:

```
console.log( getMonthAndYear(new Date()) )  
//=> {month: 4, year: 2020}

console.log( getMonthAndYear({month: 1, year: 2020}) )
//=> {month: 1, year: 2020}
```

---

In case you have a very complex interface with lots of properties, then you can add an additional optional prop `type?` to each interface like:

```
interface InputTime {
  type?: "input-time"
  month: number,
  year: number,
  foo: string,
  bar: boolean,
}

interface InputDate {
  type?: "input-date"
  month2: number,
  year2: number,
  foo2: string,
  bar2: boolean,
}
```

and then update `getMonthAndYear()` method like:

```
const getMonthAndYear = (time: InputTime | InputDate): InputTime => {

    if(time.type === 'input-time') {
        // time is a InputTime object
        return {...time}
    } else if(time.type === 'input-date'){
        // time is a InputDate object
        return {month: time.month2, year: time.year2, foo: time.foo2}
    }
}
```

So, `time.type` helps you to determine what kind of interface it is and based on that you can modify the return object to match type `InputTime`.

Comment: i see it working in the case of isValid function in this case, but i have other complex third party library functions and functions written by other devs that will not have type guards like this. I want to know a way to work around them.

Comment: You need to update your question than to explain that in details. Please don't ask half questions and then modify them again as users start posting answers. If you have further question then create a new one or post the question with full details at first only. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry that i was not clear enough on the first time asking this question.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what your requirement here is, but I have added some logic that I think might help you.

Comment: Thanks that looks like something i can use in a lot of my current use cases

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript does not know from `function isValid(date: any): boolean` that `date` is definitely a `Date` object. It only knows that `isValid` returned a `boolean`. If you want TypeScript to treat the `isValid` function as a type assertion it needs to have the following syntax.

```
function isValid(date: any): date is Date {
   // date instanceof Date, etc
}
```

The relevant section of the TypeScript docs on [Type Guards and Differentiating Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).